# VBA loop to create a new tab for every existing tab and then copy a predesignated chart template to each new tab

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, automation

I need to create a new tab for every existing tab and select a cell name on the extisting tab to rename the new adjacent tab. Next I would like to copy a template  which includes 6 charts to each of the new tabs.

Is this possible or does someone possibly already have code that could accomplish this? I am new to vba and this is a little over my head. I will go through and just do it individually but it would be awesome if this could be automated.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand you - what's wrong with copying the tabs & renaming? How many tabs are we talking about? Is it a one-off operation? Because if it is it seems to me writing a script is an overkill no?

Comment: This is currently a one off request. So i will try to explain better. I have 32 reports and i have created a set of six charts for the first tab. I now need to write a macro to create a new tab next to each existing tab and rename said tab to the value include in cell a5 and then copy the template charts to each of the new tabs. While this is a one off I forsee the organization requesting similiar reports.

Comment: Here is the code i have so far                                                                 Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub            This will create the Tabs but i am having an issue with where they are placed